# robot_pose_ekf on an inclined plane

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have some questions about combining odometry with IMU for a rover navigating on a terrain.

1. (not necessarily related to *ROS*) What is the standard method to combine IMU and odometry for a uneven terrain rover?

- Is it like, we assume a temporal plane based on IMU and use odometry data along that plane, and finally transform it to world frame?

2. In *odom_estimation.cpp* (robot_pose_ekf), absolute measurements are converted to relative odom measurements in horizontal plane, as well as only the yaw measurement of IMU is used.

- So, does that mean robot_pose_ekf is only for 2D navigation? The package summary mentions that it has a 6D model (3D position and 3D orientation)

Thank you for your time.

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32183/robot_pose_ekf-on-an-inclined-plane/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/31728/transform-laserscan-to-world_frame). It talks about how one could construct the transform tree using an IMU.

As for `robot_pose_ekf`, it relies on its incoming sensor data to perform its calculations. Wheel odometry is always 2D, just by the nature of it. Your IMU data can publish a 3D orientation to `robot_pose_ekf`, but the robot's elevation (z-value) will never change until you have a source that publishes a z-value. I'm not sure if `robot_pose_ekf` will rotate the 2D plane of wheel odometry to a world reference frame (so that the IMU's orientation can influence elevation), since I've never used it. I'm just speaking from general experience when I say that I'm not sure that it does.

That leaves your GPS and visual odometry to publish elevation data. I can't speak for everyone, but I never take the z-measurement from my GPS unit (if you're using one). I find it to be terribly unreliable. That leaves only `/vo` (visual odometry) as your source for elevation calculations. If you publish a z-value to `/vo`, you should be able to achieve 3D navigation.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-04-19**:
Thanks for your answer @DimitriProsser. I am not using vo at the moment. I think it will still assume odometry data to be on the horizontal plane even if I publish a z-value to /vo and the resulting x,y values will be wrong. May be the best is to re-write a robot_pose_ekf like node.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-04-19**:
so that I can use IMU roll, pitch data to assume the temporal plane the robot moves on to calculate odometry.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-04-19**:
If you do so, you might want to try rotating all of the sensor data into the world frame before calculation. You can then transform the data back to a relative frame for publishing.

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2012-06-19**:
The 2D plane used by wheel odometry is fixed in the x-y plane, and does *not* rotate when the robot's pitch or roll angle changes.  This was done to prevent the z-coordinate of the robot from drifting away.  That said, it would be reasonable to dynamically rotate the plane for wheel odometry.